# Binary Search Tree Delete Method

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I have implemented a Binary Search tree in C++.

For the delete method, everything works except for the last case, when the only tree is the parent and it points to two null children. 
Now the problem is: 
I wish to print out what the left and right subtrees to the parent equal to after I have deleted the subtree. They both as well as the parent should be `NULL` but when I try to output these values I get a `STATUS_ACCESS _VIOLATION`.

Here is the code for delete in question. 
I wish to delete the parent node, and set the `tree->left = tree->right = NULL.`

```
void BST_delete(string key, BST & tree) { 
    if ((!BST_has(key, tree) || BST_isEmpty(tree))) {
        return;
    } else if (tree->key == key) {
        if (tree->right == NULL && tree->left == NULL) {
            tree = NULL;                      // <-- THIS IS IN QUESTION
        } else if (tree->left == NULL) {
        ...
            } ....
}
```

MAIN:

```
int main() {
    BST bst;
    BST_init(bst);
    BST_insert("a",bst);
    BST_print(bst);
    cout << endl;

    BST_delete("a",bst);
    BST_print(bst); // <-- doesnt print anything (which is right)
    cout << bst->right; //<-- Gives me error
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a **debugger**?

Comment: OT: You should think about implementing these functions as members of BST.

Comment: @wonce, That's currently being remedied, actually, at least if some evidence of mine has led me to the correct conclusion.

Comment: I don't understand in you MAIN, you have deleted bst in BST_delete(`bst = NULL`), why do you still want to do `bst->right`?

Answer (score 0):

You can check for NULL (or nullptr):

```
voit printNode(BSTNode* p) {
     cout << ( p==NULL ? "null" : *p);
}

if (bst != NULL) {
     cout << printNode(bst->right);
     cout << printNode(bst->left);
}
```

and add this check to the BST_print function.

Comment: If the parent is null (as in the question), checking its `right` member isn't going to end too well.

Answer (score 0):

This is what's happening:

```
BST_delete("a",bst);
// bst is NULL
BST_print(bst); // equivalent to BST_print(NULL)
cout << bst->right; // Gives an error, because you 
                    // can't access a member on a pointer that is NULL
```

The last line is like saying `NULL->right`, which doesn't make sense.

I'm not sure what to tell you to fix it - as a commenter points out, why would you still want to call `bst->right` after you've deleted `bst`? Perhaps it is best to either delete that line, or do:

```
if (bst != NULL) cout << bst->right
```